# Shopify multiple currencies selector - how to show not all but only a few currencies

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, currency

Shopify support to sell in multiple currencies

https://shopify.dev/themes/internationalization/multiple-currencies-languages?shpxid=e645f265-1198-41B7-FF88-EFB9EDFB5CE0

In this documentation, I found a great example with JavaScript and Liquid of how this can be implemented.
But this example shows all available currencies in the world.

Can you please advise if there is a way to show just a few currencies,
for example: GBP, USD, EUR currencies

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation they are using the `available_countries` attributes to create a list of all available countries.

```js
<select name="country_code">
    {% for country in localization.available_countries %}
        <option value="{{ country.currency.iso_code }}">
        // more code here
</select>
```

You should be able to just filter this list down to the countries you want before creating the drop down list. Implementation of this will vary depending on which countries you want.